# How to search on array and select the element in logic app

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

In logic app I have parse json data one of field is 'content' which is array of objects.

```
{
    "content" : [ {
            "type" : "substitution",
            "name" : "start_time",
            "value" : "4:00 p.m. PDT"
          },  {
            "type" : "substitution",
            "name" : "app_type",
            "value" : "virtual"
          }, {
            "type" : "substitution",
            "name" : "end_time",
            "value" : "4:15 p.m. PDT"
          }, {
            "type" : "substitution",
            "name" : "organization_name",
            "value" : "vivendo habitasse doctus harum platea"
          }, {
            "type" : "substitution",
            "name" : "start_date",
            "value" : "Wednesday, October 7, 2020"
          } ]

}
```

Now I want to search in array with name and  return the value if is present else empty.
e.g  search by name  "start_time" it should return  value "4:00 p.m. PDT"
How Can I achieve this in logic app ? Is there any pre defined functions that lets you search

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, there is no pre defined functions for us to implement this requirement. But we can implement it by writing code, please refer to my logic app below：

**Prerequisites**: You need to create an integration account and associate it with your logic app. You can refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-enterprise-integration-create-integration-account).(I think free pricing tier for integration account is enough)

**1.** Initialize a variable named `inputName` to store the input name (here I store `app_type` for test).
[image]

**2.** Then initialize another variable named `datasource` to store the same json as yours.
[image]

**3.** User "[Parse JSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-perform-data-operations#parse-json-action)" action to parse `datasource`.
[image]

**4.** After that, use [JS inline code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-add-run-inline-code#add-inline-code) to do the search.
[image]

```
var content = workflowContext.actions.Parse_JSON.outputs.body.content;

var inputName = "" + workflowContext.actions.Initialize_variable.inputs.variables[0].value;

var result = "";

content.forEach(item=>{
    if(item.name == inputName){
        result = item.value;
    }
});

return result;
```

**5.** Running the logic app, it retrieve the value `virtual` (which its name is `app_type`).
[image]